# How to use a map in java when dealing with objects

Tags: java, object, dictionary

So, I'm creating a program that allows users to specify the insurance cover they want as part of an insurance policy. As part of it, I need to use a map in order to track the owner of each specific insurance policy.

I have seen examples of how to use a map with regards to `String` and `int` values, but nothing for self made classes (`InsurancePolicy` in my case).

So, I'm trying to do it like this, but I get the illegal expression warnings:

```
Map<String, InsurancePolicy> coverOwnerMap<String, InsurancePolicy>();
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide more information about your problem, I think, in order to get a helpful answer.  For example, give specific details about the error you are getting that you don't understand (paste the error message in) or provide code snippets that don't do what you think they should.

Comment: but its just a little thing not a major code issue. but thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, that's invalid Java. Try,

```
Map<String, InsurancePolicy> coverOwnerMap = new HashMap<String, InsurancePolicy>();
```

Comment: yep, i didnt know about that, there you go green tick.